# Which plugin to download for displaying java applet on google chrome

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, applet, object-tag

I've had a few problems recently displaying a java applet. Finally, something has displayed. but it isn't an applet. It's a little box, the width and height of my applet, asking for a plugin needed to display the applet. I am using google chrome. Which plugin do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [site](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2429779) You sure, that you have installed Java?
You can test it [here](https://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp)

Comment: That sounds mysterious, because on the [Java site](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) they say the same. There is no other plugin for google chrome what you can install to use the java applet. Maybe a other solution is to activate java in your Browser? See [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml) how to activate it.

Comment: Just because the machine has Java, does not mean it is enabled as a plug-in for Google Chrome.  Does the applet work in other browsers?

Comment: No, just a box with a cross in the top left corner

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need the [Java plugin](http://java.com/).